# How to tell if a session is active?

Tags: php, session

Per request, there are a few different ways that you can tell whether or not a session has been started, such as:

```
$isSessionActive = (session_id() != "");
```

Or:

```
$isSessionActive = defined('SID');
```

However, these both fail if you start a session, then close it; `session_id()` will return the prior session's ID, while `SID` will be defined. Likewise, calling `session_start()` at this point will generate an `E_NOTICE` if you already have a session active. Is there a sane way to check if a session is currently active, without having to resort to output buffering, the shut-up operator (`@session_start()`), or something else equally as hacky?

**EDIT: I wrote a patch to try to get this functionality included in PHP: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52982**

**EDIT 8/29/2011: New function added to PHP 5.4 to fix this: ["Expose session status via new function, session_status"](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/?view=revision&revision=315745)**

```
// as of 8/29/2011
$isSessionActive = (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE);
```

**EDIT 12/5/11: [session_status()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) on the PHP manual.**

Comment: This is maybe hacky: [`session_is_active()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788369/how-to-tell-if-a-session-is-active/7656468#7656468), but at least something I found. Thanks for the bug report anyway, nice to see this solved in 5.4.

Comment: Still a relevant question w/ the 5.4 addition, as I've just pushed to a 5.3 box and found `session_status()` missing!

Comment: That's certainly odd, as it is indeed present on my 5.4 build. Areyou saying you're using 5.3 or 5.4? Was it a custom or prebuilt PHP binary? In `phpinfo()`, do you have a "session" section? In action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/PiZmcw

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See edits to the original question; basically, PHP 5.4 and above now has a function called [`session_status()`](http://php.net/session_status) to solve this problem!

["Expose session status via new function, session_status" (SVN Revision 315745)](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/?view=revision&revision=315745)

If you need this functionality in a pre-PHP 5.4 version, see [hakre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7656468/367456).

Answer (score 15):

I worked around this by adding a couple wrapper functions around the various session creation/closing/destroying functions. Basically:

```
function open_session() {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['is_open'] = TRUE;
}

function close_session() {
   session_write_close();
   $_SESSION['is_open'] = FALSE;
}

function destroy_session() {
   session_destroy();
   $_SESSION['is_open'] = FALSE;
}

function session_is_open() {
   return($_SESSION['is_open']);
}
```

Hackish, but accomplished what I needed.

Comment: Well, this is also the solution that I have chosen... the alternative would probably have been implementing a session write handler that modifies an internal flag that you can then check, but this would have sort of defeated its own purpose because it would have to be defined in the beginning.

Comment: in the session_close function there is a stray curly bracket that needs to be a semicolon.  SO won't let me edit because not enough characters need editing. :/

Answer (score 11):

I'm running into this as well, and a setting in `$_SESSION` is not an option for me. For PHP 5.3.8:

1. If any session has been started with the request, `define('SID')` will return `FALSE`, as well as `$_SESSION` is unset.
2. This is independent whether or not `session_id()` has been used to set a session id or not.
3. After the first `session_start()`, `SID` is defined and `$_SESSION` is set to an empty array.
4. `session_destroy()` does unset the `session_id()`, it's an empty string then. `SID` will remain defined (and set to it's previous value which might be an empty string). `$_SESSION` is left unchanged. It will get reset/populated next time `session_start` is called.

With these states, especially as `session_id()` can be called in between to set the id for the *next* session, it's not possible to safely determine the session status with `SID`, `$_SESSION` and `session_id()`.

"Trying" with `session_start()` (e.g. with `@`) might not be really helpful, as this will change the session status and changing the contents of `$_SESSION` (and adding a set-cookie header if the cookie was not part of the request). It was not fitting in my case.

While I was running tests, I came across the behaviour, that you can not try to change the ini setting of `session.serialize_handler` when the session is active, not even when you set it to the same value. Same is true for [`session.use_trans_sid`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/session.use_trans_sid) which is more lightweight. This lead me to the following function:

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
function session_is_active()
{
    $setting = 'session.use_trans_sid';
    $current = ini_get($setting);
    if (FALSE === $current)
    {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Setting %s does not exists.', $setting));
    }
    $result = @ini_set($setting, $current); 
    return $result !== $current;
}
```

As far as I can see, the error is checking for active session status only (not disabled), so this should not return a false positive when sessions are disabled.

To get this function compatible with PHP 5.2, it needs a little modification:

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
function session_is_active()
{
    $setting = 'session.use_trans_sid';
    $current = ini_get($setting);
    if (FALSE === $current)
    {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Setting %s does not exists.', $setting));
    }
    $testate = "mix$current$current";
    $old = @ini_set($setting, $testate);
    $peek = @ini_set($setting, $current);
    $result = $peek === $current || $peek === FALSE;
    return $result;
}
```

Some [sandbox](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z6OaZB).

Comment: While this is still somewhat 'hacky', I'm impressed by your technique. It was my thinking that there were some attributes of the problem that would lend itself to inference (such as what you're doing here), I was just unable to find them. Very nice!

Comment: Also, is the sandbox your site? The opcode analysis is sweet.

Comment: No, that's not my site, but I like it, too. :) Right now I'm unsure with that hack if it works for PHP 5.1 (I might need that).

Comment: @Salathe was very kind and measure the routine against various PHP 5.1 versions (https://gist.github.com/1265615#gistfile1.txt), looks really like something useful for backward compat.

Answer (score 5):

The following code only dumps one session_id() for me, not two

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
session_destroy();
echo session_id();
```

If you're having difficulties with this still you can try creating a variable to check, that you destroy when you destroy the session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['intialized'] = 'This will not print';
$_SESSION = array(); // Unset all variables
session_destroy();
echo $_SESSION['initialized']; // No output
```

Comment: But if you use session_write_close(), the session's closed, but $_SESSION data is still there, which is what I think the OP's getting at... how do you check if the session file itself is still in-use?

Comment: Yeah, you basically posted the same solution I did, setting a variable before closing it (in any way) and checking that variable...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good drop in replacement that won't break stuff when you move to 5.4:

```
if(!function_exists('session_status')){
    function session_active(){
        return defined('SID');   
    }
}else{
    function session_active(){
        return (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE);   
    }        
}
```

Comment: As I stated in my original question, that's an inadequate solution; if you call `session_start()` and then call `session_write_close()`, then `defined("SID") === true` even though the session is not open. Such a technique can only determine if a session has been started during the request cycle -- and not whether or not one is presently open. It may work for some use-cases, but it's not a replacement for `session_status()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ken, if the session is destroyed, the $_SESSION array should not be available...or at the very least, your values should be unset.  So, in theory (untested) you should be able to check the array for a value to know if anything is currently set.

Comment: `session_destroy()` nor `session_write_close()` unset `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple places you need to check to verify the session is active:

1- cookie exists and is not expired
2- underlying session storage mechanism (file system or database) has a record matching the cookie.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the goal/intention.

Comment: Perhaps yes. I am more used to dealing with sessions that have custom functionality. It would be good to encapsulate the session into a class so that when the destructor is called, or session_write_closed member function is called you update a boolean flag in that class showing active or not.

Comment: It's to avoid `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`. This bug has more information on the use-case: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52982