# PHP: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() comes only in windows

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP sessions that have already been started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648984/php-sessions-that-have-already-been-started)

I have run a my  PHP project on windows and also Mac  with same code . But I got this error when I run my project in windows not in Mac.

error message is .

```
A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
```

which is come only on Windows system. But In Mac I didnt get any error message. 
 Please any one give me a solution .....

Comment: can you track all the times you used session_start?

Comment: You have the `error_reporting` values different for both these machines

Comment: @lbu Yes , I track the session start,  and I have tried this too, if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start();} . but didnt get right solution

Comment: @PHP Bugs please tell me where can I find error reporting values

Comment: You can see this from your `php.ini` file. Find out where this file is located from the `phpinfo` page.

Comment: try <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
?>

Comment: I had tried that but didnt get right solution

Comment: `if (!defined('SID')) session_start()` work for me

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You said that you starts session with a check:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

The fact is the $_SESSION always exists and if you aren't put something in it then it will be always empty, so the statment will return always true.

Comment: Thanks! 
I used PHP 5.6 for developing ( used session_status() for checking session) but on server only supports to PHP 5.3 so I got it fixed simply by your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I didnt know why windows shows the error and Mac dont.
But You can try to replace all `the session_start()` by

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }
```

This will may help you..

Answer (score 5):

This message is an `E_NOTICE`. The reason you're only seeing it on the Windows machine is most likely because you have `error_reporting` set differently.

If you search `php.ini` for `error_reporting` you should exclude `E_NOTICE` if you don't want to see it.

Alternatively, fix your code to not start a session more than once. Ideally, you would only have one core code file that would start your session and no other instances of `session_start()` (ie. don't put it on each page). You can then include this on each page, or create a routing pattern that will ensure initialisation code is called on each pageload.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at session.auto_start in your php.ini (http://php.net/session.auto-start), most likely the session is automatically started

Comment: I have checked the php.ini file and found auto_start=0