# Calling Php Function With Ajax Request to change session variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a communication problem between home.php page and user.php page.

on Homepage there is link for Log out

```
<span class="log_out"> <a id="logOut">Log Out</a></span>
```

When a user click this page ajax call will be started

Here is my ajax call

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#logOut" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
         url: 'class/user.php',
         data: "logout=1",
         success: function(data) {
            $('body').append(data);
         }
         });
        });
});
```

in user.php I have this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
        echo "alert";
        $_SESSION['user'] = 0;
    }
?>
```

When I click logout, alert is being appended in body, but session variable was not changed at all.

I dont know what's going on here.

Comment: Did you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10649019/1003917

Comment: It's something about the IF in user.php

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yeah I just added it, at least I am not getting session warning, but the problem is still here

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years but when i click log out body is appending alert

Comment: Thanks for helping guys again I found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
    $_SESSION['user'] = 0;
    Print_r ($_SESSION);
```

}

I found solution thanks for helping guys, I just need to add session validation on my if else clause, although I have this validation on top of the page, when I added it inside the function, problem fixed

Comment: I don't see any `else` here .. or did you just mean `if` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `session_start();` to the top of your user.php file and also debug with the echo after a session is set, otherwise you'll get the warning you're getting at the moment.

Comment: thanks for helping but, it is already done in every page, I posted the answer bleow