# PHP session has already been started

Tags: php, session

I have a page on my website that calls a php file using ajax. I require the user to be logged in to access either page, and use `session_start()` on the page that calls the php file (let's say `main.php` calls `bg.php`). I include a `session_start()` on `bg.php` as well, because I need to access the session variables. However, I am spammed with php notices that say

`A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`

So, I tried using

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

However, I kept getting the error, so I tried removing it entirely, because it said it was being ignored anyways. However, then `bg.php` stopped recognizing session variables. How can I stop getting the notices?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648984/php-sessions-that-have-already-been-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the session status with [`session_status()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) function to avoid repeated session start. For example:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to write a library file, that is included at very first place in all .php files. It contains functions and startup code, that is nneded by all/many other pages. This helps to create clear structures and avoid copy and paste common code parts.

*.php

```
<?PHP
require_once("lib-standard.php");
# .... more code
```

lib-standard.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
# more startup code (locale, timezone, login, check users, check rights, ...)
# common functions
# common classes
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to address php session control like this:
after verifying the user, I'll set a session variable. 
like:

```
   $permitted_chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

   $_SESSION['loggedIn']=generate_string($permitted_chars, 20);
```

then on the top of every page I want my session control to be:

```
        <?php
        session_start();
         if (empty($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){
          header("Location: login.php");
          exit();
         }
```

edit: Also, if you are loading external pages, like a dbconnect.php page, you would put just the:

```
        <?php
        if (empty($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){
         header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
       }
```

at the top  in those files....

if I really go robust, then I store the "logged in" generated code in a db table at login, load a couple of identifiers (like user and password) into the session variables,  Then after my initial check, I would check if the session is valid like

```
     " select count users from user_tbl where `name`=`".$_SESSION['name']."` and `pass`=`".$_SESSION['pass']."` and `key`=`".$_SESSION['loggedIn']."`"
```

then

```
       if ($count=="0"){
        header("Location: login.php");
      exit(); 
       }
```